# iphone - Programmatically determine which UIViewController on Storyboard called my class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my storyboard, i have two UIViewControllers both using the class CustomViewController.

From the viewDidLoad function of CustomViewController.m, how can I determine which UIViewController in my storyboard is calling this class?  For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
if(CALLED_FROM_VC1_IN_STORYBOARD)
{
// load from data feed 1
}
else
{
// load from data feed 2
}
}
```

What should I replace `CALLED_FROM_VC1_IN_STORYBOARD` with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `prepareForSegue:sender` method on the first VC to pass the data along to a property on your second VC.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    segue.destinationViewController.originatingVC = segue.sourceViewController;
}
```

Though you probably don't want to keep the entire VC in memory, so maybe refactor that to just the bare data. Even if you have to pass along every property!

viewDidLoad is generally called after prepareForSegue, but beware that UIPopovers are an exception.

Comment: You may also need to apply a cast.

Comment: Any use, OP? Do I need to clarify?